# Как работает приведение типов ключей при создании объекта?

Tags: javascript

```js
var obj = { "1": 0, 1: 9, 2: 3 } 
console.log(obj["1"]); // 9
console.log(obj);
```

Почему вернулось значение свойства 1, а не "1"?
Куда пропало свойство 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что ключом в объекте всегда является строка (ну ладно, ещё `symbol`, но он тут не при чём). Получается, ты в литеральную запись объекта включаешь два одинаковых свойства (разрешено в ES3-, ES5 non strict, ES6+ в любом режиме) и последнее из свойств побеждает (перезаписывает более раннее значение).

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @HovhannesShaxulyan, а можно тогда принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него?

Comment: Да, конечно, недавно здесь, только осваиваюсь.